# How to access url parameters when configuring child router

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to generate some routes dynamically in a child router basing on a parameter provided within the url.

So I have my main router configured with that route :
mydomain.com/#/page/**:page**   that is loading a module "page"

And in my module page I have a configureRouter function which is supposed to fetch the sections relative to the page specified in the url before to add them in the child router:

```
public async configureRouter(config, router){
    page = ???
    sections = wait fetchPageSections(page)
    //for each section, add route in child router
}
```

My problem here is how to retrieve the **:page** parameter, since this will be available only (if I understand well) in the activate() function, that will be called after configureRouter(). However, since that part of the route has already been "matched" in the parent router, I think there should be a way to retrieve it in the configureRouter function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to retrieve the `:page` parameter in the `configureRouter()` method, because as far as I know, at this point the new route has not been triggered yet.

You can retrieve the `:page` parameter in the `created()` method.

```
created() {
   let page = this.router.parentInstruction.params.page;
   // do something and add routes
   //this.router.addRoute({ route: "test", moduleId: "test", nav: true, title: "test" });
   //this.router.refreshNavigation();
}
```

A second option would be using a global object to hold the desired parameter. You could inject this object in the `constructor()` method of the view component. However, this would be an overkill and unsafe to use. I do not think it is a good idea.

A third option, and the easiest one in my opinion, is using `mapUnknownRoutes()` for dynamic routes:

```
router.configure(config => {
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
     //read the instruction.fragment to get
     //you can return a promise and make async requests
     return instruction;
   });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I implemented a mix of solutions 1 and 3. I load the routes in the created() method (once I get access to the page parameter) and before i use mapUnknownRoutes() to redirect to an empty section while the routes are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The router you are passed in `configureRouter(config, router)` is the child router. Luckily, it has a `parent` property that will provide you with what you want.

`router.parent.currentInstruction.params.page` should give you what you're looking for: the `page` parameter from the parent router.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the currentInstruction of the parent router is still null when entering the configureRouter function of the child module ... I think it set only before calling the activate function ...